# WebRequest GetResponse not responding, operation times out

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to make an HttpWebRequest to send data via POST to a REST web service, and then follow-up with an additional HttpWebRequest to download a response after processing.

The POST is sending binary data up to the web service, as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseAddress + uploadURIRequest);
uploadRequest.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
uploadRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
uploadRequest.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;
uploadRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

using (Stream writeStream = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (FileStream readStream = new FileStream(fileStreamFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[] data= new byte[readStream.Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(data, 0, (int)readStream.Length);
        writeStream.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);

        readStream.Close();
    }
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

Then the next request is made to tell the web service to process data on the server and return the status response.

```
HttpWebRequest processRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseAddress + processURIRequest);
processRequest.Timeout = 10000;
processRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
processRequest.ContentType = "GET";

HttpWebResponse processRequestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)processRequest.GetResponse();

using (Stream processRequestResponseStream = processRequestResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    //Do stuff...

}
```

When I change content-type, it works for XML data.  However, when I keep it as shown above with binary data, the operation always times out...even if I increase the timeout to longer than 10 seconds.  The processing that it is doing should not take this long to return.

When I debug, it always hangs on the line with GetResponse:

```
HttpWebResponse processRequestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)processRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: your process request doesn't look set up properly. You set the ContentType to get and don't have a setting for content length or method

Comment: Dont you have an Off-by-one error in your code? You are setting ContentLength=FileStream.Length, but only uploading FileStream.Length-1 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake in trying to simplify the code that I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
HttpWebResponse uploadRequestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)uploadRequest.GetResponse();
```

after writing to the stream resolved this issue.

Comment: After writing to which?